# discrepancies between google places api nearby search and results returned on Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

if I point google Maps to a location `[-20.1419057374276,-157.33203817679]`
 and then carry out a nearby search for "tour operator" I get, in the case of that location, 9 results `https://www.google.com/maps/search/Tour+operator/@-21.2333094,-159.7948598,14z`

if I use Google Places API (in this case in R using httr:GET - I have tried googleway also) I do not get any results returned (status:"ZERO_RESULTS"):

res.wild<-GET(paste("`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=",paste(centers$lat[i],centers$lon[i],sep=","),"&radius=35000&keyword=tour+operator&key=",myKey,sep=""`))

where centers$lat[i],centers$lon[i] is -20.1419057374276,-157.33203817679

I used to use the radar search which is no longer available but seemed to return results consistent with a direct search on google maps. Going through the documentation, I cannot see from where this discrepancy come.
Anyone has any idea?

thanks!

Comment: try to edit code in a format.

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates shown in the URL of Google Maps are not reliable as they take zoom into account. If you want to get exact coordinates, use other methods such as Geocoding.

The `-20.1419057374276,-157.33203817679` coordinate points to Mauke, Cook Islands: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D-20.141906%252C-157.332038

If you want to get nearby places from Rarotonga, Cook Islands, then you can e.g. use `-21.229237,-159.776349` instead: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D-21.229237%252C-159.776349

Try this request using the above coordinates:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-21.229237,-159.776349&radius=35000&keyword=tour+operator&key=YOUR_KEY

The output is close to what you get in Google Maps:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -21.2573049,
               "lng" : -159.7311111
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -21.25565152010728,
                  "lng" : -159.7299870701073
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -21.25835117989272,
                  "lng" : -159.7326867298927
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "d54699b006411b5a5f9450ee2b30e88ad7deec44",
         "name" : "Captain Tamas Lagoon Cruizes",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 645,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102745446521532412613\"\u003eCaptain Tamas Lagoon Cruises\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAA6O-c8lb1bdh75I9dWRqjmTZanPhSx8LgNlVxR9ZMtoLkQMQ0uzSMGFr_xtfwdID9wPS2DlNIXO4aqHc_eVGzjDjPNzLyO_f8YvIp6gaP3xoYGRfKoOb_aZpKOqS2INnMEhA75QSRQC4FQnM8sXketTROGhRC1SgaNX6Hg1S6PIxlVQEOiVM4CQ",
               "width" : 859
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJmSbDLojTV3EROL5C9_iW6kg",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "P7V9+3H Ngatangiia District, Cook Islands",
            "global_code" : "53C2P7V9+3H"
         },
         "rating" : 4.8,
         "reference" : "ChIJmSbDLojTV3EROL5C9_iW6kg",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "travel_agency", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "user_ratings_total" : 102,
         "vicinity" : "Muri Beach, Muri"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -21.258145,
               "lng" : -159.732045
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -21.25663512010728,
                  "lng" : -159.7310816201073
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -21.25933477989272,
                  "lng" : -159.7337812798927
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "354b255213a808490880fe1b9551d0f442aae382",
         "name" : "Koka Lagoon Cruises",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 3024,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/103124684904518750526\"\u003eHuong Tran\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAbNLjafLjIMjmUaJ-jilVZuJfWt79C_IoPEC-epFVSSSSlwQLo9_RMVRWl_dAAx4naup6P8aCr-F-TtTtzWpB_cI0-B1RbBcbp4mIvGxqLQvBeX6DWKi-gaT1UjsfKhG4EhDDBz4JWPKmCx4Mq3hiUv1iGhTKRpHYORs6lj-VYV-bqwTo6VFw0g",
               "width" : 4032
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJu4ZfKXbUV3ERrKo9dhOCJiI",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "P7R9+P5 Ngatangiia District, Cook Islands",
            "global_code" : "53C2P7R9+P5"
         },
         "rating" : 4.9,
         "reference" : "ChIJu4ZfKXbUV3ERrKo9dhOCJiI",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "user_ratings_total" : 67,
         "vicinity" : "Muri Beach, Rarotonga"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -21.2204492,
               "lng" : -159.8285893
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -21.21907502010728,
                  "lng" : -159.8273637201073
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -21.22177467989272,
                  "lng" : -159.8300633798927
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "6ca2b13851e47e4474fd197888d503d352de2f15",
         "name" : "Tik-e Tours",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 4032,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117619328803821181982\"\u003eA Google User\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAdq12AeQCjoIpk09GCOx-laja1_iJ2Vzgnonu1quJ0bIzdOjV6YOvBHYoJT8hXwlyaUGB5C5o14HS3i-FUdwOuln7OFsY56r-bguBuQGV5_ukiyNHrCiCeRU5M7PhaLo2EhAfer7M013sz3i2uVsxTEfSGhQqWr9yhhB8UKcNGps3kOxCFcQa3A",
               "width" : 3024
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJGe7bPVnQV3ERHI7vgH-Ou3c",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "Q5HC+RH Arorangi District, Cook Islands",
            "global_code" : "53C2Q5HC+RH"
         },
         "rating" : 4.9,
         "reference" : "ChIJGe7bPVnQV3ERHI7vgH-Ou3c",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "user_ratings_total" : 10,
         "vicinity" : "Arorangi District"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -21.2655311,
               "lng" : -159.7819558
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -21.26411742010728,
                  "lng" : -159.7805932701072
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -21.26681707989272,
                  "lng" : -159.7832929298927
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "91cdd05c5d95d60981a890fd54886ebcad4b8ba9",
         "name" : "Snorkel Cook Islands",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 2304,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/112866284698762632354\"\u003eFe&#39;ena Syme Buchanan\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAd8e9zm-Wsa8hR-YkjI-bbLB_N_qJ9k5TOaYAjiyYhrHUJjQkdC9DmFc3RZVnQKpcS-QY7A3AtJPIG5OLH8dNSAwiQUB2tYmB-CMD6ZDRUSqqBpa3P_p2y9jc2sv9Lqd4EhDJooK75NFPEz0k_YsX38WMGhS1znNvtNWs-xwCg1OL0sF1JRHRZQ",
               "width" : 3456
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJKTe2bjLXV3ERHUapU18Vydg",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "P6M9+Q6 Takitumu District, Cook Islands",
            "global_code" : "53C2P6M9+Q6"
         },
         "rating" : 5,
         "reference" : "ChIJKTe2bjLXV3ERHUapU18Vydg",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "user_ratings_total" : 1,
         "vicinity" : "Rarotonga"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -21.2031499,
               "lng" : -159.7862431
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -21.20180492010728,
                  "lng" : -159.7848997701073
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -21.20450457989272,
                  "lng" : -159.7875994298927
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "6c6524b3437e98c139998b5ec06ea81fd3ff2f5f",
         "name" : "Black Watch Charters",
         "place_id" : "ChIJP8sjaZbRV3ERaB06jfdehkY",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "Q6W7+PG Avarua District, Cook Islands",
            "global_code" : "53C2Q6W7+PG"
         },
         "rating" : 0,
         "reference" : "ChIJP8sjaZbRV3ERaB06jfdehkY",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "user_ratings_total" : 0,
         "vicinity" : "Avarua District"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -21.1994895,
               "lng" : -159.8003902
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -21.19841532010728,
                  "lng" : -159.7989554201073
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -21.20111497989272,
                  "lng" : -159.8016550798928
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "5f02f471fe2868a51943041aa684874f8269ef7b",
         "name" : "Raro Safari Tours & Concierge Desk",
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 3024,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100947574557964297982\"\u003eJAY PILISI\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAA34pKKofPm9XF97_CcfSLVGq3y2AHn-linLaeEc1RfHRjpbJThl5EQuxKKmamNZ1i4cvqSu1-65He6nLolErQJLXEFDMPis4-5dKmK2TXS2-jyEsnrkcKKPiYqZD3B3jcEhC_GBl65rela41ctpewfxc3GhSt4oGQNCPui4k4j6vFU4o3hQWDDw",
               "width" : 4032
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJgRilfy3RV3ERpi1MKCgisSw",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "R52X+6R Avarua District, Cook Islands",
            "global_code" : "53C2R52X+6R"
         },
         "rating" : 4.9,
         "reference" : "ChIJgRilfy3RV3ERpi1MKCgisSw",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [
            "tourist_attraction",
            "travel_agency",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "user_ratings_total" : 10,
         "vicinity" : "Avarua District"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -21.249997,
               "lng" : -159.822227
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -21.24868352010728,
                  "lng" : -159.8209628201073
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -21.25138317989272,
                  "lng" : -159.8236624798928
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "affb3957b65c2ca105d0c5e63e547e22b6d73493",
         "name" : "Adventure Cook Islands Ltd",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 1063,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111619238938552241021\"\u003eAdventure Cook Islands Ltd\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAQ4B12jlUrWlqwK1gWdfEEoGndrBWhviA8DTSI-Q-UoGmyR_7b7mkbtI361dC9dAZh3-Z0YlOYTdvVze9Vuw9qjFNecFMcPGO30ISi6DXCPezDEM_eTZj_mPbCDdLh8cyEhBlTzcXyYr7Atj69fRyPkVhGhQI_eSnR2CEQfCZNOXfM9UOC7uytA",
               "width" : 1417
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJOw686NzQV3ERYaRq_jbcJjw",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "Q52H+24 Arorangi District, Cook Islands",
            "global_code" : "53C2Q52H+24"
         },
         "rating" : 4.9,
         "reference" : "ChIJOw686NzQV3ERYaRq_jbcJjw",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "travel_agency", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "user_ratings_total" : 21,
         "vicinity" : "Kavera Beach, Arorangi Rarotonga"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -21.220265,
               "lng" : -159.828848
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -21.21891637010728,
                  "lng" : -159.8274922201073
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -21.22161602989272,
                  "lng" : -159.8301918798927
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "aca36479a072b313810c37ac835e50440bf3b81f",
         "name" : "Dive Rarotonga",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 337,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102784390999532361399\"\u003eDive Rarotonga\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAW5A88HqZDDXA6her_GXw7zoxj2wB_U1O-tUubEBFNCteiAoPscB0o5-N5KvN-oY9TIaMnTD1-UhU1wNiX7-nSVMiUTIUcZIzEZFsDgJrO-xPL0hbm5jE887kq3V1VYVIEhCpMlOYcEqSDWLEDAPcnodCGhSBnJ1dO8GpFHZEnTMP6l9t2zpZpA",
               "width" : 600
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJkSU-1V3QV3ER3yczeMV8I_k",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "Q5HC+VF Arorangi District, Cook Islands",
            "global_code" : "53C2Q5HC+VF"
         },
         "rating" : 4.9,
         "reference" : "ChIJkSU-1V3QV3ER3yczeMV8I_k",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "travel_agency", "point_of_interest", "store", "establishment" ],
         "user_ratings_total" : 33,
         "vicinity" : "Yellow A-Frame, Main Road, Arorangi District"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -21.252595,
               "lng" : -159.730144
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -21.25122567010727,
                  "lng" : -159.7289091701073
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -21.25392532989272,
                  "lng" : -159.7316088298927
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "f0b212e097fc057cb51138594070cfe5c014d436",
         "name" : "Pacific Divers",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJRUYyzojTV3ER9iL5iSVfHNo",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "P7W9+XW Ngatangiia District, Cook Islands",
            "global_code" : "53C2P7W9+XW"
         },
         "rating" : 0,
         "reference" : "ChIJRUYyzojTV3ER9iL5iSVfHNo",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "travel_agency", "school", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "user_ratings_total" : 0,
         "vicinity" : "Ara Tapu, Muri"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -21.2012422,
               "lng" : -159.8060292
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -21.19968582010728,
                  "lng" : -159.8046350701073
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -21.20238547989272,
                  "lng" : -159.8073347298927
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "e53fbdf110553cb3a56e69dedfc348e1da4e0172",
         "name" : "Turama Pacific Travel Group",
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 525,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104663734301544398423\"\u003eA Google User\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAvgs-ezM5FNldJ1bfCf_sV0Ql58Nj54UKuirPef1T0FNqc6U2YLdpREuexg20VBWNwRdet--vuGenVsazreVEio-ezp4VEzYbrMv2BVbILKGswlL83NN8hT0BPEK3gTOaEhADvZmluOWXh0kRYgtcRE3oGhQ95v3wdXzFgfh06tOico2RmMJWiA",
               "width" : 700
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJuUvKeLbRV3EROJNkUZhNG5g",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "Q5XV+GH Avarua District, Cook Islands",
            "global_code" : "53C2Q5XV+GH"
         },
         "rating" : 5,
         "reference" : "ChIJuUvKeLbRV3EROJNkUZhNG5g",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "travel_agency", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "user_ratings_total" : 1,
         "vicinity" : "Avarua District"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, i was indeed targeting Ma'uke. the problem is reverse: I get results returned in Google maps but not in Places API. the interesting thing indeed is that this discrepancy is more flagrant in sparse places. after playing with it, it looks like it is an issue with the keyword part of the api search. If I restrict by type (eg type=tourist_attraction), I get more consistent results between Maps and Places api.

Comment: Glad to hear & happy to help! :)

Comment: If this answer helped you resolve your issue please consider accepting it as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers